# why javascript ++ operator increase more than one step in my code?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a code to create an abbreviation hash table and its repeated count but my code increase it more than 1 step.

```
var dict={};

function addToDict(str) {
  let abr = [str[0], str.length, str.slice(-1)].join('');
  return dict[abr] = ++dict[abr] | 1;
}


console.log(
  addToDict("salam"),
  addToDict("saaam"),
  addToDict("Sadegh"),
  addToDict("hosein"),
  addToDict("hasan"),
  addToDict("hesan"),
  addToDict("hesan")
)
console.log(dict);
```

The result is

```
{ s5m: 1, S6h: 1, h6n: 1, h5n: 1 }
```

instead of this

```
{ s5m: 2, S6h: 1, h6n: 1, h5n: 3 }
```

why!!??

Comment: You're using the bitwise or `|`. You probably want to use the logical or operator `||`.

Comment: I think you mean *let dict[abr] = ++dict[abr] || 1* instead of *dict[abr] = ++dict[abr] | 1*, so a 2 pipe char *||* instead of 1. As with 2 is an or operator that provide the default value, with one is a bitwise operator.

Comment: Yeah you are right, thank you for your comment " Mario Alexandro Santini"

Comment: To debug this I recommend you open up `node` in a console window. Execute each sub-expression one by one to make sure it is what you expects. In other words, do e.g. `let str = "salam"` followed by `[str[0], str.length, str.slice(-1)]` to make sure that expression is okay. Then do the same with the `join` call appended. Then do the same but prepend `++`. Then do the same but add the `|1` at the end. If at any stage you notice some error, then you know where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to increment the `dict[abr]` using `++dict[abr] || 1` IMO. Bit wise should not be used here.

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise operator will work like this.

```
     2 (base 10) = 0010 (base 2)
     1 (base 10) = 0001 (base 2)
----------------------------------
 2 | 1 (base 10) = 0011 (base 2) = 3 (base 10).
```

This way it becomes 3.

This will help you to understand the use of "|" operator.

You can use "||" operator if you want either incremeted value or 1.